# Visibility of villages in Mapbox

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

In my Mapbox GL project, I have a layer with towns and villages which looks like this:

```
{
            "id": "towns",
            "type": "symbol",
            "source": "composite",
            "source-layer": "place_label",
            "minzoom": 1,
            "maxzoom": 14,
            "filter": [
                "all",
                [
                  "match",
                  ["get", "type"],
                  ["town", "village", "hamlet"],
                  true,
                  false
                ],
                ["match", ["get", "name"], [
                  // list of villages
                ], true, false]
            ],
            "layout": {
                "text-variable-anchor": ["top", "bottom", "left", "right"],
                "text-allow-overlap": true,
                "text-ignore-placement": true,
                "icon-allow-overlap": true,
                "text-field": ["get", "name"],
                "text-font": ["Roboto Regular", "Arial Unicode MS Regular"],
                "text-size": [
                    "interpolate",
                    ["linear"],
                    ["zoom"],
                    3,
                    8,
                    22,
                    16
                ]
            },
            "paint": {
                "text-halo-color": "hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.95)",
                "text-halo-width": 1,
                "text-halo-blur": 0.4
            }
        },
```

The text-size zoom interpolation works fine for the towns. However, the village will only show up after a zoomlevel of 9. Is there any way I could make the villages visible at all time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the [Mapbox Streets Tileset](https://docs.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/reference/mapbox-streets-v8/#place_label) you're using only includes those villages in the data after zoom 9, so there is nothing you can do in the style to make it show up earlier.

You'd need to create your own dataset which includes the data you want at lower zoom levels (and maybe just check this is the cause first in Mapbox Studio data view).